# Speeding up mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a mysql query to join four tables and I thought that it was just best to join tables but now that mysql data is getting bigger the query seems to cause the application to stop execution.

```
 SELECT 
                        `purchase_order`.`id`, 
                        `purchase_order`.`po_date` AS po_date, 
                        `purchase_order`.`po_number`, 
                        `purchase_order`.`customer_id` AS customer_id , 
                        `customer`.`name` AS customer_name, 
                        `purchase_order`.`status` AS po_status, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`product_id`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`po_item_name`, 
                        `product`.`weight` as product_weight,
                        `product`.`pending` as product_pending,
                        `product`.`company_owner` as company_owner,
                        `purchase_order_items`.`uom`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`po_item_type`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`order_sequence`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`pending_balance`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`quantity`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`notes`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`status` AS po_item_status,
                        `purchase_order_items`.`id` AS po_item_id
                      FROM `purchase_order` 
                      INNER JOIN customer ON `customer`.`id` = `purchase_order`.`customer_id`  
                      INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON `purchase_order_items`.`po_id` = `purchase_order`.`id` 
                      INNER JOIN product ON `purchase_order_items`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`
GROUP BY id ORDER BY `purchase_order`.`po_date` DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

[image]

my problem really is the query that takes a lot of time to finish. Is there a way to speed this query or to change this query for faster retrieval of the data?

heres the EXPLAIN EXTENED as requested in the comments. 
[image]
Thanks in advance, I really hope this is the right channel for me to ask. If not please let me know.

Comment: Please share the results of `Explain Extended`. Also share the indexing details on the table(s)

Comment: Are tables which are joined properly indexed?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya im not sure what to give but will try to search first.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri im not so sure what are proper indexing of the columns. will search for it.

Comment: You need to index all the columns which are frequently used in joining tables and also in `where` clause.

Comment: hi @MadhurBhaiya i've added the explain extended result in my post.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri i've added indexes to all tables columns and the result is good but not so good. now it will only took 29 seconds compared to 36 seconds

Comment: Just go with query caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this give you the correct list of ids?

```
SELECT id
    FROM purchase_order
    ORDER BY`po_date` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 20
```

If so, then *start* with that before launching into the `JOIN`.  You can also (I think) get rid of the `GROUP BY` that is causing an "explode-implode" of rows.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT id ... (as above) ...) AS ids
    JOIN purchase_order po  ON po.id = ids.id
    JOIN ... (the other tables)
    GROUP BY ...   -- (this may be problematic, especially with the LIMIT)
    ORDER BY po.po_date DESC   -- yes, this needs repeating
    -- no LIMIT
```

Something like this

```
SELECT 
                        `purchase_order`.`id`, 
                        `purchase_order`.`po_date` AS po_date, 
                        `purchase_order`.`po_number`, 
                        `purchase_order`.`customer_id` AS customer_id , 
                        `customer`.`name` AS customer_name, 
                        `purchase_order`.`status` AS po_status, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`product_id`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`po_item_name`, 
                        `product`.`weight` as product_weight,
                        `product`.`pending` as product_pending,
                        `product`.`company_owner` as company_owner,
                        `purchase_order_items`.`uom`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`po_item_type`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`order_sequence`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`pending_balance`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`quantity`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`notes`, 
                        `purchase_order_items`.`status` AS po_item_status,
                        `purchase_order_items`.`id` AS po_item_id
    FROM (SELECT id, po_date, po_number, customer_id, status
            FROM purchase_order
            ORDER BY `po_date` DESC
            LIMIT 0, 5) as purchase_order 
    INNER JOIN customer ON `customer`.`id` = `purchase_order`.`customer_id`  
    INNER JOIN purchase_order_items
         ON `purchase_order_items`.`po_id` = `purchase_order`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN product ON `purchase_order_items`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`
    GROUP BY purchase_order.id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this is is about 20 to 30 times faster to my query but i still need to change the query because im issue with the limit as it gives me more than what i have expected.

Comment: The `LIMIT` is in the derived table (subquery).  Or are you getting more rows after the `JOINs`?  If so, maybe you do need the `LIMIT` outside.  In that case, does the `ORDER BY` need another column to make it deterministic?

Comment: Yes im getting more rows after the join but without the join the correct number of rows are correct but when i added the joins it became more than what is expected.

Comment: will try your suggestion. :)

Comment: its not working. because if i add limit it duplicates the ids.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez - OK, the `GROUP BY` was necessary; add it back in.

Comment: thanks a lot Rick. I've got it 20 to 30 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that `purchase_order.po_date` and all id column are indexed. You can check it with below query.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will do now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that data is getting bigger. I would suggest doing sharding and then you can parallelize multiple queries. Please refer to the following article

[Parallel Query for MySQL with Shard-Query](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/01/parallel-query-mysql-shard-query/)

Answer (score 0):

First, I cleaned up readability a bit.  You don't need `tick` marks around every table.column reference.  Also, for short-hand, using aliases works well.  Ex: "po" instead of "purchase_order", "poi" instead of "purchase_order_items".  The only time I would use tick marks is around reserved words that might cause a problem.

Second, you don't have any aggregations (sum, min, max, count, avg, etc.) in your query so you should be able to strip the GROUP BY clause.

As for indexes, I would have to assume you have an index on your reference tables on their respective "id" key columns.

For your Purchase Order table, I would have an index on that based on the "po_date" in the first index field position in case you already had an index using it.  Since your Order by is on that, let the engine jump directly to those dated records first and you have your descending order resolved.

```
SELECT 
      po.id, 
      po.po_date, 
      po.po_number, 
      po.customer_id, 
      c.`name` AS customer_name, 
      po.`status` AS po_status, 
      poi.product_id, 
      poi.po_item_name, 
      p.weight as product_weight,
      p.pending as product_pending,
      p.company_owner,
      poi.uom, 
      poi.po_item_type, 
      poi.order_sequence, 
      poi.pending_balance, 
      poi.quantity, 
      poi.notes, 
      poi.`status` AS po_item_status,
      poi.id AS po_item_id
   FROM 
      purchase_order po
         INNER JOIN customer c
            ON po.customer_id = c.id
         INNER JOIN purchase_order_items poi 
            ON po.id = poi.po_id
            INNER JOIN product p 
               ON poi.product_id = p.id
   ORDER BY 
      po.po_date DESC 
   LIMIT 
      0, 20
```

Comment: I added group by id because i get duplicate results base on the id which i think is just duplicate.